# ListRows.Count Returns Inconsistent Results

Tags: excel, vba, count, vsto, listobject

I have a strange problem with two of my Excel Tables residing on two different worksheets in my project. I am using VSTO but VBA shows the same result: an empty table's row count has 0 rows in one case and 1 row (I presume the insert row) in another case.

**The Setup**

Two worksheets: Sheet1, Sheet2
Two corresponding named Excel Tables: Sheet1Table, Sheet2Table

Both tables are empty, i.e. they have one empty row, which is insert row that cannot be deleted.

I run the following code to determine the number of data rows (i.e. excluding the header row):

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject sheet1Table = Globals.Sheet1.Sheet1Table;
int numberOfListRows1 = sheet1Table.ListRows.Count;
```

and

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject sheet2Table = Globals.Sheet2.Sheet2Table;
int numberOfListRows2 = sheet2Table.ListRows.Count;
```

The result is that `numberOfListRows1` is 1 and `numberOfListRows2` is 0 although the result (whichever is correct) should be the same. I compared the table and worksheet properties, as well as the source files in Visual Studio, and I could not spot any differences. Any idea what I should be looking for (and which result is the correct one)?

Comment: Did u use .add  and .delete to add rows and on the other use insert rows, delete rows  , as list only counts .add .delete , so you may have skewed the counter with manual editing of table?

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be what's causing it. If all rows are deleted manually the count is "0". So, would "1" be the correct result and I need to reset the table somehow before counting in case it's empty?

Comment: Turns out that deleting (manually or in programmatically) corrects it. The problem was the way the table was created. I selected the header row and one empty row, and then clicked "Format as Table". The result looks like an empty table with an insert row. Even a `COUNTA` across that row is 0. But it is in fact a data row that is counted when doing a `ListRows.Count`. Seems obvious and almost silly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA I used these subs to test your case:

```
Sub Sheet1TableRowsCount()
    Dim numberOfListRows1 As Integer
    Dim sheet1Table As ListObject
    Set sheet1Table = Sheet1.ListObjects("Sheet1Table")
    numberOfListRows1 = sheet1Table.ListRows.Count
    Set sheet1Table = Nothing
End Sub

Sub Sheet2TableRowsCount()
    Dim numberOfListRows2 As Integer
    Dim sheet2Table As ListObject
    Set sheet2Table = Sheet2.ListObjects("Sheet2Table")
    numberOfListRows2 = sheet2Table.ListRows.Count
    Set sheet2Table = Nothing
End Sub
```

These are the tables:
[image: table1] [image: table2]

When these tables are created (incorrectly) by selecting the headers and one empty row and then formatting the selection as a table, they have one empty row. This row has no content, `COUNTA` across the row is 0, and it appears like the insert row that cannot be deleted. It is however a valid data row, so `ListRows.Count` will get the value of `1`.

Similarly, if you fill in some data and manually delete those entered values (using <kbd>Delete</kbd>) so that your tables would look like at the beginning, the results will still be `1`.

If you delete rows manually or programmatically (using something like `Sheet1.Range("Sheet1Table").Rows("1").Delete`), the `ListRows.Count` will then yield the value of `0`.

The solution to determining the actual count of data rows is to check `ListRows.Count`, and if the result is 1 - delete the row after checking if it does not contain actual values. This whole situation can be avoided if an empty table is created by selecting the header row only before clicking *Format as Table*. The insert row is then created automatically and not counted as a data row (the result of `ListRows.Count` in this case is `0`).

Comment: If u use vba .add and .delete method for tables , it won't happen

Comment: no, I mean when you are adding and removing rows, if you use vba .add and .delete   instead of Excels Insert/Delete     "The ListRows object returned does not include the header, total, or Insert rows."

Comment: @StevenMartin - Thanks. I got what you meant and updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I checked once again also with VBA, and it really looks like deleting rows manually yields a count of 0. When working with an initially empty table the result is 1. Instead of `DataBodyRange.Rows.Count` I used `ListRows.Count` as in the question, which should count the rows without the special rows (header, total, ...). I'm not sure whether it should be 1 or 0 ir only the empty insert row is shown. Is there a good reason for using `DataBodyRange` instead?

Comment: I accidentally checked `DataBodyRange.Rows.Count` instead of `ListRows.Count`. To my mind `ListRows` is a better approach for you. When I noticed it I updated the answer. But I see there's a difference between what we have. You say that initially the result of `ListRows.Count` for you is 1, and for me that is 0.

Comment: Yes, that just adds to the mystery. It takes a bit of time to test in both environments with an untouched empty table. I was hoping for some potential factors affecting the result. Manual deletion seems to be one of them, which, one or the other way, puts the table into a wrong state, and that's bad news. Option now is a workaround able to detect both cases and handle them.

Comment: I would loop through values in the **first** row only, probably using `DataBodyRange` (if this would not yield an error). And if there are no actual values in the first row, I would delete the row using `.Delete`. I suppose this way the state of the table would be restored. I propose to use it only on the first row, because if I test scenarios where more datarows are present, I always get the correct count (If I had 2 datarows and they were all empty, I would still get 2 as a count. But if there's just one visible datarow, we cannot be certain on the count.

Comment: looping only if the count of rows is 1 (my case) or 0 (your case)... Because otherwise the count would be correct? What `.Count` result do you get if you have more than 1 data rows?

Comment: It happens only when the table is empty, i.e. multiple data rows are counted correctly, and also a single row containing data shows as 1 row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97057/discussion-between-jerry-and-zygd).